# Razor: Display procentage

Tags: razor, decimal

I thought there would be an easy solution but I didnt succeed in finding anything that worked!

```
var squatPro = sumTotalSquatWeight/sumTotalVolume;
```

It's basically just this line, I don't know how to make it to decimal, since the result now is just 0 when the numbers are 9120/14895 = 0,61.

Adding  `* 100` at the end of the code gave 0 as well so that wasn't a solution!

(I'm not using MVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to cast the numerator to a decimal:

```
var squatPro = (decimal)sumTotalSquatWeight / sumTotalVolume;
```

And if you want to round to 2 decimal places you can use something like this:

```
@squatPro.ToString("0.##")
```

Or if you need it as a percentage you can use this:

```
@(string.Format("{0:P}", squatPro))
```

Comment: Thats fantastic! Thanks a lot!